# Load ad from Widget

Tags: android, admob

I am work with this guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial 
to add ad to my app and all work great when i fallow this guide

But if i want to load ad from widget,The first thing when click one widget it's don't work it's even not load the ad.

My problem is i think in this line:

```
            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd("Dont know what put here");
```

If you see the words "Dont know what put here" it's because the normal thing that need to be there is MainActivity.this Or this only this

But what i do when click on widget is open settings on phone

What i need to do?

This code in opUpdate inside the widget class

i Open first of all

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i],views)
```

what i need to replace with the ad

```
            Intent additionalCallSettingsIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        ComponentName distantActivity = new ComponentName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.GsmUmtsAdditionalCallOptions");
        additionalCallSettingsIntent.setComponent(distantActivity);
        PendingIntent pInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, additionalCallSettingsIntent ,0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button,pInt);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i],views);
    }
}

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID").build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

When prees on this widget:

[image]

First of all some ad like this pop up:

[image]

how i do this? thet first of all in first prees pop up ad and then go to app

Comment: Can you please share some screenshots or something to make us understand your problem better.
I didn't understand what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: I Make test widget on the center:
http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=tynnw4q4zimz.png
I want to do,When click on the button in widget then open ad
http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=qv1zzoelj3dj.png

Comment: Place your interstitial ad code in the OnCreate method of the Activity which will open when you click on the widget.
This way whenever the user opens the activity he/she will see the ad first.

Comment: Look what i add to post

Comment: try calling the function requestNewInterstitial after appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i],views);

Comment: Finally i make timer that every 3 seconds check if ad is loaded and if true then the ad pop up
In short, Thank you for the help :)